# Erro em Ajax valor null de retorno

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho um função em ajax:

```
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("FiltraLevatamento", "Consulta")",
                    data: JSON.stringify(jsn),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {

                            result(data); 


                        $("#modalboxProcessa").modal("hide");

                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, txtStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $("#modalboxProcessa").modal("hide");
                        $("#modalboxErro2").modal("show");

                    }
                });
```

Na minha maquina local funciona corretamente, só quando eu publico no servidor da erro no ajax.

Alguém sabe me dizer qual é o problema?
Tenho praticamente o mesmo ajax só que me retorna outros dados diferentes, e esta funcionando normalmente.

Comment: No console, quando é feita a requisição, qual o erro retorna?

Comment: qual é o erro??

Comment: Esse é o problema apresenta o erro 404, ja coloquei para detalhar o erro, mas não apresenta nada. Ja vai direto para o "error:"

Comment: o seu servidor deve estar sem acesso externo... reveja as configurações dele e troque os 127.0.0.1 para 0.0.0.0

Comment: Ele esta com acesso externo.

Comment: utilize um plugin do browser para requisições REST para obter mais detalhes do problema

Comment: Esse controller `Consulta` por acaso não está sob uma *Area* no seu projeto MVC ?? E também, se a action `FiltraLevatamento` espera algum parâmetro e esses parâmetros estiverem diferentes a rota não é efetivada.

Comment: Se da erro 404 é que ele nao encontrou, você consegue acessar o ajax via navegador?